# How to end crosshair line where x meets y on line chart in high charts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

An image might explain what I'm trying to do easier.
[image]

When you enable crosshairs they go all the way from the bottom of the chart to the top. How do I create a crosshair that only touches the x and y points? instead of going through the whole chart?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mosueOver` point's event and create a custom crosshair by using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class.

```
point: {
  events: {
    mouseOver: function() {
      const chart = this.series.chart,
        x = this.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
        y1 = this.plotY + chart.plotTop,
        y2 = chart.plotHeight + chart.plotTop

      if (!chart.customcrosshair) {
        chart.customcrosshair = chart.renderer.path().attr({
          'stroke-width': 1,
          'stroke-dasharray': '8,3',
          stroke: 'red'
        }).add();
      }

      chart.customcrosshair.attr({
        d: ['M', x, y1, 'L', x, y2]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/osphtxjg/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Would is the recommended way of removing the crosshair when the user does not have the mouse over the graph? Using point.events.mouseOut seems to be called every time they move between points.

I need to remove the crosshair when they mouseout of the graph

Comment: Hi @SpaceOso, You can wrap `onContainerMouseLeave` function. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3dq71zy9/